# Multiple different website hosting on same port 443 and same server or ip in IIS8

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, iis-8

Currently, two different websites are hosted on different ports in the same server IIS8. Now we would like to move those websites on HTTPS 443 in the same server IIS and two different domains are available [www.example1.com](http://www.example1.com), and [www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com) thus which type of SSL certificate need? Does the different certificate work for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 8 and above supports SNI, so multiple sites can bind to the same IP:443,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

If you find your attempts fail, you can go deep to Windows HTTP API layer to see if you get SNI certificate mappings configured properly,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

or generate a diagnostics report,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

There isn't special requirements on certificates as long as they are valid for server authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 443 port with both different websites in iis with different domain names and server Name identification setting

[image]

you can buy any trusted root CA server certificate for your domain and you have to buy two different certificates.